# Rails 3,how to update a habtm table in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, rails-console

I have Awards - Awards_Categories - Categories in a HABTM association.

I updated my routes so that

```
resources :categories do
   resources :awards 
end
```

I have two awards that didn't have a category so now accessing them from the admin is not working.

How would mess with this in the console.  Its pretty straight forward, I need award(15) and award(16) to have category 4...

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
category = Category.find(4)
[15, 16].each{|k| Award.find(k).categories << category }
```